# Storing value of variable in local storage

Tags: javascript

I have simple web app, with variable (var VacationBalance=21).I want this value to decrement by 1 each time the user click on a button (with the id: decrement). Also, I want this to be saved on the local storage..However, it is not working at all.

Here is the HTML:

```
<h1>Current Vacations: <span id="VacationsBalance"></span></h1>

    <p><button id="show-form">Submit a new Vacation</button></p>

    <form id="VacationForm" style="display:none;">

        <div class="from-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Select Vacation Type</label>
            <select class="form-control">
                    <option>Annual</option>
                    <option>Casual</option>
                  </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="decrement">Confrim</button>
    </form>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
var VacationBalance=21;

var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

$(document).ready(function(){

    if (localStorage) {

        $("#VacationsBalance").text(data);}
        else {

    $("#VacationsBalance").text(VacationBalance);
}


})

window.onload = function() {

    var showForm=document.getElementById('show-form');

    showForm.addEventListener('click',function(){

        document.getElementById('VacationForm').style.display="";
    });

}


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#decrement").click(function(){
        VacationBalance--;
        $("#VacationsBalance").text(VacationBalance);

        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(VacationBalance));


    })
})
```

Appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code. Here, if localStorage is present and data is also present, we load VacationBalance variable with the value from localStorage. Button click will update the localStorage.

```
enter code here
var VacationBalance = 21;
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

$(document).ready(function(){
    if (localStorage) {
        if(data) {
            VacationBalance = parseInt(data, 10);
        }
        $("#VacationsBalance").text(VacationBalance);
    }
    else {
        $("#VacationsBalance").text(VacationBalance);
    }
});

window.onload = function() {
    var showForm=document.getElementById('show-form');
    showForm.addEventListener('click',function(){
        document.getElementById('VacationForm').style.display="";
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#decrement").click(function(){
        VacationBalance--;
        $("#VacationsBalance").text(VacationBalance);
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(VacationBalance));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

when you read the data from localStorage, you'll need to update your VactionBalance value to reflect the new value; here's a cleaned up version:

```js
// get your initial setting from default or localStorage
var VacationBalance=21;
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
// if localStorage had the value, update VacationBalance
if(data) {
    // get the integer value in case it was stored as a string
    VacationBalance = parseInt(data, 10);
}

// set up jQuery on document.ready
$(document).ready(function(){
    // VacactionBalance will now always be accurate to default or loaded localStorage value
    $("#VacationsBalance").text(VacationBalance);

    // refactored to jQuery like the other stuff
    $('#show-form').click(function() {
        $('#VacationForm').css('display','');
    });

    // added all three into one document.ready call
    $("#decrement").click(function(){
        VacationBalance--;
        $("#VacationsBalance").text(VacationBalance);
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(VacationBalance));
    });
});
```

the only thing you were really missing was updating your VacationBalance value from localStorage on page load.